# Do gradient descent on function with no input using pytorch

Tags: pytorch

What's the correct way to do gradient descent on an arbitrary function with *no* input using Pytorch?

```
x = torch.tensor(x_init, requires_grad=True)
opt = torch.optim.Adam([x])
cost_fnx = cost(x)
for iteration_count in range(100):
    opt.zero_grad()
    cost_fnx.backward()
    opt.step()
```

When I tried the above, I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved variables after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved variables after calling backward.
```

Comment: what do you mean by no input? Can you write the desired expressions mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to backpropagate on the same graph multiple times. You most likely need to recompute the cost value (your *regularizer* function since it only has the model's parameters as input) to backpropagate again. Something like:

```
x = x_init.requires_grad_(True)
opt = torch.optim.Adam([x])
for iteration_count in range(2):
    cost_fnx = cost(x)
    opt.zero_grad()
    cost_fnx.backward()
    opt.step()
```

Comment: But would opt.step automatically update x? Otherwise this would just be passing the same x each time.

Comment: @user3180 Remember that `x` is a parameter of your model. When calling `cost_fnx.step()` is will update the parameters registered to the optimizer using the cached gradients... this includes `x`. So the answer is yes.